# Is there a proof of Benford's Law?

Tags: statistics, intuition

As stated by Wikipedia ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law)):

> Benford's law, also called the first-digit law, states that in lists of numbers from many (but not all) real-life sources of data, the leading digit is distributed in a specific, non-uniform way. According to this law, the first digit is 1 about 30% of the time, and larger digits occur as the leading digit with lower and lower frequency, to the point where 9 as a first digit occurs less than 5% of the time.

I find this fascinating and confusing.  Benford's original contribution came after the first statement of the phenomenon, and in it he used a data sample with over 20 thousand entries.  It has since been tested on data samples that number in the hundreds of thousands.

Statistically, it seems sound.  But **why** should it be true?  What is the *intuition* behind this phenomenon?

Most importantly, *is there a proof?*

Comment: The intuition behind ist is scale invariance. The distribution of leading digits of distances between cities, say, should be the same if we measure in centimeters or in inch or in alpha-centaurian gargle-feet. This is only possible if the fractional parts of the logarithms of the values are *equidistributed*. Under this assumtion, the law can be proved. But how will you prove it about "real-life sources of data" if there is no mathematicla definition of "real-life source of data".

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I have heard this argument a number of times, but I think it begs the question. *Why* should the distribution of the leading digit be independent of the unit of measure? It is certainly not true of the height of human beings, for example. I think an important requirement is that the distribution spans several orders of magnitude, and that the probability density is not “too wild” within this range.

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, let $X$ be a positive random variable with a continuous distribution. I think it should be fairly easy to prove that Benford's law holds in the limit for $X^a$, as $a\to\infty$.

Comment: This blog post is relevant: http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2012/07/29/benfords-law-and-baseball/

Comment: Related question: [Why does Benford's Law (or Zipf's Law) hold?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781/why-does-benfords-law-or-zipfs-law-hold?rq=1)

Comment: See the open-access [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1177009869) by T. Hill, "_A Statistical Derivation of the Significant-Digit Law_," Statist. Sci. Volume 10, Number 4 (1995), pp. 354-363.

Comment: Terence Tao on the subject: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/benfords-law-zipfs-law-and-the-pareto-distribution/

Comment: see for some examples http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267113/question-about-benfords-law, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267164/the-prime-numbers-do-not-satisfies-benfords-law