# M.SE reputation distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

What distribution does the reputation points per user follow on math.SE (or on entire stackexchange)?

Is there a mathematical explanation/model of it?

Comment: Can a query be made to get that distribution? Or at least the raw data?

Comment: OK, just made a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/65376) myself and it seems the data can be stored as a CSV-file.

Comment: @LLLLL What have you tried? :-)

Comment: Related: When the site was much younger I tested user reputation against Benford's Law.  The results are [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/8100/2370).

Comment: This is a question that is appropriate on both Math.SE and Meta.Math.SE.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a histogram with 20 bins of the data contained in the CSV file. On the x-axis, I have plotted the logarithm base 10 of the reputation scores. We can see that many users just come here to ask one question and then never get much beyond 100 points (people who also use other SE's) or 1 point (throwaway accounts). Hence the peaks around 2 and 0. So we should filter these two peaks and look at the residual data to see if there's some well-known distribution emerging. I expect something with a long tail, hence the need to use the log-transformation.

[image: Histogram]

And here's the [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/65376) I used to fetch the data.

Here's an extra plot of the [rank-size distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank-size_distribution) of the tail of the previous distribution. The slope of the line is about -0.92.

[image: Rank-size distribution]

Comment: That small circle at the bottom right point in the second graph... that's Arturo, right?

Comment: Yes, that's him. And the second point on the left from that one is Arturo and Qiaochu. ;)